# Is Dark Crimson ever destroyed?

Tags: agarest-war

In *Record of Agarest War Zero*, Summerill first gets Dark Crimson created and it doesn't get destroyed because Calinou's hammer is destroyed (however the plans for remaking it are preserved but there wasn't enough time to rebuild it thanks to Mila going to explode).

In *Record of Agarest War*, the party gets all the components to create the hammer and destroy Dark Crimson. However, destroying it was only one of the options to save Winfield (the other was destroying Summerill). However, Vashtor steals the Rainbow Drip and it seems that he didn't have it if you end up recruiting him (a requirement for the true end).

When I was looking up whether the hot springs CG actually exists in *Record of Agarest War 2*, I saw an image of Fiona being tortured and the screenshot has Mobius talking about how Eva is nothing more than a doll. The image was a screenshot of a YouTube video and I am nowhere near there yet. I needed to know what Mobius was doing to Fiona and how far off I was in getting to that point to save her (apparently it's near the very end of the 3rd generation at the ending split), Mobius says to Fiona that she'll be saved if the party bring Dark Crimson to him.

There's also another Agarest game called *Record of Agarest War: Marriage*, but I have no idea where it sits on the timeline and it seems to put emphasis on a rainbow blade rather than Oathsworn or Dark Crimson, making me think it might not be in it.

So I am wondering, is Dark Crimson ever destroyed?